# Static variable inside a static function?

Tags: c++, static

Simple C++ Simulation of Java String Literal Pool

Hi,

I can't make a call from a private static variable in my MyString class. Any idea?

```
static void displayPool() {
    MyString::table->displayAllStrings();
}
StringTable* (MyString::table) = new StringTable();
```

both of those are declared in MyString class. table is a private variable.

Thanks.

EDIT: headerfile

```
#ifndef MYSTRING_H
#define MYSTRING_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
#define POOLSIZE 100

class StringTable {
 public:
    StringTable();
    int addString(const char *str);
    char* getString(int i);
    void deleteString(int i);
    void displayAllStrings();
    void addCount(int);
    void minusCount(int);
 private:
    char** array; //da pool
    int* count;
    int size;
    int numStrings;
};

class MyString {
 public:
   MyString(const char*);
   MyString(const MyString&);
   ~MyString();
   static void displayPool();
   MyString& operator=(const MyString &);
   char* intern() const;
 private:
   int length;
   int index;
   static StringTable* table;
   friend MyString operator+(const MyString& lhs, const MyString& rhs);
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, const MyString & str);
 }; 

#endif
```

Comment: what is the error from the compiler?

Comment: it just says error within this context. But when I tried MyString::table it says MyString::table is private

Comment: _Paste_ the actual error message into your question. Just because the error is more-or-less meaningless to you (otherwise you would know what the problem is ;-]) doesn't mean it is to everyone else.

Comment: Show us the relevant class declaration code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want in this case is the following:

```
void MyString::displayPool() {
    MyString::table->displayAllStrings();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
static void displayPool() {
    MyString::table->displayAllStrings();
}
```

This is not doing what you think it is doing. It is defining the free function `displayPool`. All that the keyword `static` does is to keep the function local to the source file in which the function is defined. What you want is to define the static member function `MyString::displayPool()`:

```
void MyString::displayPool() {
    table->displayAllStrings();
}
```

The `MyString::` before `displayPool` is essential. You do not want the `static` keyword here; adding that would be an error. Finally, note that there is no need for the `MyString::` to qualify `table`. A static member function can see all of the static data members without a need for qualification. The only reason you would need to qualify `table` is if there was a global variable named `table`; then `table` would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a static variable inside your static function you should just do:

```
static void displayPool() {
    static StringTable* table = new StringTable();

    table->displayAllStrings();
}
```

However I have a feeling the problem might be asking you to create a static method for some class. You might want to re-read the problem.

Comment: We are trying to simulate Java string literal pool. The static variable was already declared. The purpose of this function is to display all the elements inside the table.

Comment: I think what you're asking then is to use a private static field from inside a static method. You need to make the method a static member of your class (and you will not want the static modifier on it which has a completely different meaning).

Answer (score 0):

have you declared

```
StringTable* table;
```

in the class definition of MyString with the public access specifier?